# Starting new Activity in OnCreate

Tags: android, zxing

I got android app based on 2 activities. The Main activity is just a input field and a button to get some user information. When the user press the button a barcodescanner (ZXING) will start.

Every thing works perfect. But know i try to check in the onCreate if user information is already known. If its true -> start the barcodescanner. But it looks like the barcodescanner activity starts up twice, because:
pressing back button once: annother barcodescanner wil be active.
pressing back button twice: Main activty will be active.

this is the check inside onCreate:

```
if(pref.length() == 6){
       startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 

}
```

and this is the function called when clicking the button:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

            final EditText edit =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.panelID);   
            if(edit.getText().toString().length() == 6){
                String temp = edit.getText().toString();
                Log.e("click", temp);
                Editor e = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                e.putString("panelID", temp);
                e.commit();

                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ongeldige invoer (6 cijfer id)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            break;
        }
    }
```

What do i do wrong?

Comment: Why are you using final on edit?

Comment: copy paste mistake.. (final is removed)

Comment: Finnaly i found the bug.. I was testing while device was on my table (screen was black because camere coudnt see anything). The back button didnt work because of this (i gues some funcion in ZXING librarie causes this). When i use it normal it all works perfect :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trouble seems to be more with how you are managing the lifecycle of the activity. If you post your Activity's onCreate() method's code, we might be able to see better what you're trying to accomplish and suggest a solution accordingly.

Comment: Finnaly i found the bug.. I was testing while device was on my table (screen was black because camere coudnt see anything). The back button didnt work because of this (i gues some funcion in ZXING librarie causes this). When i use it normal it all works perfect :D

Comment: Yeah orientation can make life a little tricky to handle. make sure you determine what is the correct time to start your second/next activity, with respect to the first activity's lifecycle.

Comment: Barcode Scanner / ZXing does nothing to the back button. This isn't it.

Comment: @SeanOwen: Yup. You're right. My bad that I did not point it out. Without a closer look at the code, I can't say much, but since a new object of the Activity is instantiated when the orientation changes, and onCreate() gets called again, it *could* be the reason for the problem above.

Comment: ye, it was. orientation change was called ,but i didnt noticed it(barcodescanner stays in landscape).

Answer (score 1):

the `barcodescanner` doesn't start twice 
it goes back to main activity which create another `barcodescanner`

try to remove the check in `onCreate` and see the result

Comment: when i remove the check in onCreate. the back button in the barcodescanner works good. But i wanne start barcodescanner if user info is known when starting the app

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should not start the scanner every time in `onCreate()`. I imagine that the first time, you go to the scanner, and your parent activity gets destroyed. When you go back, it has to be created again. But this starts the scanner again. And then, when you immediately go back again, it hasn't yet been destroyed this time.

It is nothing to do with the app hijacking the back button. It does not. Back always works.

Answer (score -1):

This might work

Clear the data of your edit text after you call startActivityForResult like

```
edit.setText("");
```

This should make your check fail when you go back

Comment: didnt solve the problem.. Verry strange i just compiled a working version. But after that i compiled again (without making any changes in de code) and problem was back..

Comment: if that is the case , try to clean the project